# Text field keeps switching to other typing fields since the update to 18.10

Tags: keyboard, screen

Since updating to 18.10, my text field keeps switching to other typing fields on the same screen.  As well my windows, on anything including Firefox keeps scrolling through the page quickly all by itself. 
Any assistance would be great.. Getting really frustrated!

Comment: If this is a laptop, your thumb may be hovering or resting too close to the trackpad.

Comment: Nope,  it's a regular puter,  not a tablet or laptop..

Comment: Try unplugging your mouse, or try a different mouse if you have one.